# accuracy of dense optical flow

Tags: image-processing, motion, opticalflow

Currently I am learning dense optical flow by myself. To understand it, I conduct one experiment. I produce one image using Matlab. One box with a given grays value is placed under one uniform background and the box is translated two pixels in x and y directions in another image. The two images are input into the implementation of the algorithm called TV-L1. The generated motion vector outer of the box is not zero. Is the reason that the gradient outer of the box is zero? Is the values filled in from the values with large gradient value? 
In Horn and Schunck's paper, it reads

*In  parts of  the image where the brightness gradient is  zero, the velocity 
estimates will simply be averages of the neighboring velocity estimates. There 
is no local  information to constrain the apparent velocity of motion of  the 
brightness pattern in these areas.*

*The progress of this filling-in phenomena is similar to the propagation effects 
in the solution of the heat equation for a uniform flat plate, where the time rate of change of temperature is proportional to the Laplacian.*

Is it not possible to obtain correct motion vectors for pixels with small gradients? Or the experiment is not practical. In practical applications, this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in so called homogenous image regions with very small gradients no information where a motion can dervided from exists. That's why the motion from your rectangle is propagated outer the border. If you give your background a texture this effect will be less dominant. I know such problem when it comes to estimate the ego-motion of a car. Then the streat makes a lot of problems cause of here homogenoutiy.

Comment: From your webpage, you have a lot of research experience about optical flow. We know optical flow calculation is a computation-intense task. OF is a popular research topic. Every year papers on OF can be found on CVPR, Siggraph and ICCV/ECCV.  Is there any practical application that uses OF calculation?

Comment: There is a nice video from Michael J. Black,which has done some pioneering work in OF. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tIwpDuqJqcE He for example used the OF for animations in several films (e.g. Matrix). If you want to analyse videos motion is a important properties. E.g. see action classification (https://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/wang/improved_trajectories). I have use dense optical flow fields to classify violent video content. I know some medical computer vision that apply OF.

Comment: OF is a powerful tool to analyze motions between frames. The applications you mentioned require no real time response. Can I draw the conclusion that OF is not a nice choice for real time application. Hierarchical block matching may be more proper.  I have another question. Are there any good methods for tackling occlusions? I find occlusions will distort motion field.

Answer (score 0):

Two pioneers in this field Lukas&Kanade (LK) and Horn&Schunch (HS) are developed methods for computing Optical Flow (OF). Both rely on brightness constancy assumption which feature location pixel values between two sequence frames not change. This constraint may be expressed as two equations: I(x+dx,y+dy,t+dt)=I(x,y,t) and ∂I/∂x dx+∂I/∂y dy+∂I/∂t dt=0 by using a Taylor series expansion I(x+dx,y+dy,t+dt)  , we get (x+dx,y+dy,t+dt)=I(x,y,t)+∂I/∂x dx+∂I/∂y dy+∂I/∂t dt…  letting ∂x/∂t=u and ∂y/∂t=v and combining these equations we get the OF constraint equation: ∂I/∂t=∂I/∂t u+∂I/∂t v . The OF equation has more than one solution, so the different techniques diverge here. LK equations are derived assuming that pixels in a neighborhood of each tracked feature move with the same velocity as the feature. In OpenCV, to catch large motions with a small window size (to keep the “same local velocity” assumption).